# Unit testing javascript using Jasmine - Karma : How to mock variables used inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**Function need to test:**

```
function validate() { 
   var isOk   = false; 
   var radios = $('input[name="abc"]:checked', '#parentDiv'). val() ;

   If(radios === "ok" )    
      isOk = true;

    return isOk; 
}
```

I want to write test case for the above code. I am using Jasmine-Karma for achieving that.  I have a doubt
How do i mock the radios variable which is getting value from a jquery selector and assign to it a mocked value,  so that test case can continue testing rest part of the remaining function

**Test case:**

```
describe("validate ok check",  function() {
it("validate returns true", function () {
expect(validate()).tobe(true);
}) ;
}) ;
```

Currently on running the test case the radios variable is getting assigned undefined value,  but i want to mock it to get "ok" value assigned to it to successfully pass the testcase.

Comment: `'input[name="abc"]:checked',` i suppose you don't need to have a space between here.

Comment: Do you have any question?

Comment: @jai why you deleted your comment?  You gave a non context answer to my question above and then deleted your answer and my comment where even i elaborated the question for better understanding.  Please let other people answer or please let me know what details you need and which part is not clear?

Comment: See what i saw that i asked. because my posted answer does not answer your question because of that i deleted it, which is good. Now coming back to your post. Still the question is missing and it is very unclear what do you require from SO?

Comment: Jai: could you please let me kmow which part is not clear.? My question is how i mock a variable in test case. I told lot of people around and they understood the question.  Please let me know which part is not clear?  I will try to elaborate more.  Thanks

Comment: You'd stub the call to jquery. This is a two-line function turned into many more.

Answer (score 1):

In a Karma context you are supposed to test the JS-only functionality. Your code contains JQuery which depends on an existent DOM (browser), so it's not very suitable to these kinds of tests.

You could mock JQuery itself in this case. Since you are using it as a global variable, you can simply overwrite it in the test case:

```
$ = function(selector) {
  if (selector) === 'input[name="abc"]:checked', '#parentDiv' {
    return { 
      val: function() { return 'ok'; }
    };
  }
};

describe("validate ok check",  function() {
  it("validate returns true", function () {
    expect(validate()).tobe(true);
  }) ;
}) ;
```

Note: this is a very direct way - you could use jasmine's mock instead to make it more reliable (e.g. also register what you expect to have been called from jquery and how many times, etc).